# How can I login an external social login with IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have setup Asp.Net Identity in my application, and would like to have the following setup:

- Have a selfmade username&password authentication as `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`
- Have external providers (e.g. Google, Facebook) which authenticate as `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme`

My social login looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ExternalLogin")]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin([FromQuery] string provider, [FromQuery] bool rememberMe)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("SocialLoginCallback", "SocialLogin", new
        {
            rememberMe
        });

        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("SocialLoginCallback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SocialLoginCallback([FromQuery] bool rememberMe)
    {
        // Grab the external login information from the http context
        var loginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (loginInfo is null)
        {
            return Problem();
        }

        var signinResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(loginInfo.LoginProvider, loginInfo.ProviderKey, rememberMe, true);

        if (signinResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

My startup google auth looks like:

```
    authBuilder.AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GoogleClientSecret"];
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        });
```

However, I noticed that the login is still executed with `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`.

After examining why, the problem seems to stem from the `var signinResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(loginInfo.LoginProvider, loginInfo.ProviderKey, rememberMe, true);` call. Internally this runs into a call to `await Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, userPrincipal, authenticationProperties ?? new AuthenticationProperties());`, which has the ApplicationScheme hardcoded.

How can I get this to work as I would like to have?

I would like to distinguish both logins in a middleware, and as of now, the only way to do this would be to check the respective claims, but I'd rather just to a simple check which auth scheme the login is using. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default authentication method ，You can set `DefaultScheme` in `ConfigureServices/Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //......
    services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(option =>
            {
                option.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            })
            .AddGoogle(option => {
                option.ClientId = "xxx";
                option.ClientSecret = "xxx";
            });
}
```

I set the login page as the default Identity login page, when I access the action whitch has `[Authorize]` attribute , the login page has two ways to log in.

[image]

If the app have multiple instances of an authentication handler , You can use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = xxxx)]` to Select the scheme with the Authorize attribute.

You can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to learn more details about **Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET** **Core**

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am already doing this, and this definitely also works, but in my case it is not about the default when it comes to ultimately authenticating the user, but rather about how I even assign an authentication scheme in the first place

Comment: Hi , Do you expect to have only one login page, and when the user enters their username and password, the code automatically recognizes which authentication method to use?

Comment: My goal would be to have two ways to login, with external providers (google etc.) using a different scheme like "External", while my regular selfmade username & password login should use the application scheme. I'm not sure if this is best practice, but this would feel natural to me at least

Comment: I have edited my answer , when user want to log in, The Login page provides two ways to log in.

Comment: Thanks Xinran, my setup already looks like this but I think my main issue is still not tackled - The ApplicationScheme is deeply baked into some of the external login code, and I am not sure how I can change that to a scheme I pick for myself?

Comment: Hi , Your question is The login page only provide `ApplicationScheme` to Authentication ?But When you want to Use multiple authentication schemes , you only need to add `.AddGoogle(googleOptions => { ... })` behind `services.AddAuthentication()`, Which .net version is in your project? can you provide your `Startup.cs` ?